# React JS App freezes the browser whenever typing something

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am quite new to React JS and was trying to make an app. However whenever typing something in a textbook, the whole app seems to freeze and then stop working.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { auth } from './firebase';
import styles from '../static/SignIn.module.css';
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

import {
    // createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
    signInWithEmailAndPassword,
    onAuthStateChanged,
    // signOut,
  } from "firebase/auth";


export default function SignIn(){

    const [user, setUser] = useState({});
    const history = useNavigate();

    onAuthStateChanged(auth, (currentUser) => {
        setUser(currentUser);

        });

    
    // const goBack =  () => {
    //         history.push('/')
    //       };
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

    const signIn = async() => {
        try {
            const user = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(
              auth,
              email,
              password
            );
            history.push('/home')
            console.log(user);
          } catch (error) {
              console.log(error)
            if (password.length < 6){
                alert('Password should be at least 6 characters!')
            }
          }
        }

    return(
        <div className={styles.main}>
            <div className={styles.center}>
                <h1>Login</h1>
                <div className={styles.form}>
                    <div className={styles.txt_field}>
                        <input type="text" id='text' name='text' value={email} onChange={e => setEmail(e.currentTarget.value)} required/>
                        <span></span>
                        <label>Email ID</label>
                    </div>
                    <div className={styles.txt_field}>
                        <input type="password" id='password' name='password' value={password} onChange={e => setPassword(e.currentTarget.value)} required/>
                        <span></span>
                        <label>Password</label>
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" value="Login"  onClick={signIn}/>
                    <div className={styles.signup_link}>
                        Not a member? <Link to="/signup">Signup</Link>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Any help would be appreciated because this is stopping me from progressing further, as I need to rerun the app using `npm start` in order to make it work.

Comment: Hey there! Can you try replacing e.currentTarget.value with e.target.value and see what happens?

Comment: @AmitMaraj Still hangs!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your issue is that on every render of the `SignIn` component you call the `onAuthStateChanged` listener. I have never used this but my guess is that it would need to be called only once, when the component mounts.

So you could do something like this instead:

```js
export default function SignIn(){
    const [user, setUser] = useState({});
    const history = useNavigate();


    React.useEffect(() => {
      onAuthStateChanged(auth, (currentUser) => setUser(currentUser))
      // Notice the empty dependency array, there to make sure the effect is only run once when the component mounts
    }, []) 

    
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

   // ... 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think everything is fine as I have tried running your code without the firebase functions and just removing the styles, just rendering the input button and it works fine and the events occur perfectly for setting email and password field. But I think you should make little amendments to your code. Please first check user object whether if it contains any data or not before pushing home route.